# xhr.js:210 DELETE http://localhost:3000/posts/62575cb61cb27c6417732193 403 (Forbidden) / cannot delete document

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, cors

I am using axios for the request of my own api, everything works correctly except the DELETE request, I looked for information about the error but I have not found the solution. when I send the request to the server I get this error: "xhr.js:210 DELETE http://localhost:3000/posts/62575cb61cb27c6417732193 403 (Forbidden)".

I put this line of code in Package.Json to avoid problems with CORS:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8080/api"
```

This would be my api, for the operation I pass the post id by url and the user id:
(I tried it in postman and it works without any problem)

```
router.delete("/:id", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
        if (post.userId === req.body.userId) {
            await post.deleteOne();
            res.status(200).json("the post has been deleted");
        } else {
            res.status(403).json("you can delete only your post");
        }
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
});
```

and this is where I consume my api:

```
const Post = ({  date, _id,userId, description }) => {
   const handleDelete = async () => {
        try {
            await axios.delete('posts/' + _id, { userId: currentUser._id })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    return(
       <div onClick={handleDelete }>
      //component content
       </div>
    )
}
export default Post
```

Comment: First of all `post.userId === req.body.userId` this can let any user delete any other user's post, just by sending different I'd. Second, do your code send this 403? Because it looks like that.

Comment: thanks for the observation, and yes, I send a status of 403.

Answer (score -2):

I solved it, sending a data object to my api (inside that object I put the user id):

```
const handleDelete = async () => {
        try {
            await axios.delete('/posts/' + _id, {
                data: {
                    userId: currentUser._id
                }
            }
            )
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should probably deserialise the user from the token rather than allowing anyone to send an arbitrary value

Comment: At the moment I only have the user created without any token but I am going to add it